# I am getting net::err_aborted 404 angular for a particular page in my application and only in a specific laptop

Tags: angular, angular-material, development-environment

I am getting the error which I mentioned in my title only on a particular page and only in a particular laptop in my development environment. My project uses some internal CSS similar to Angular Material and React.js. But that doesn't have some components to implement datasource tables with save/edit buttons so I am using Angular Material tables in that page.

So why I am getting 404 error only on a particular screen, and that too in my manager's laptop?

Comment: Are you getting the problem after hosting in IIS ? Have you tried in Google chrome’s incognito window ?

Comment: I am getting this problem when I open app in a different laptop and worked fine after deleting cache and I dont know all the some I am facing issue with the cache.

Comment: When ever I push some new changes its not reflecting the screen even after the changes got deployed and this also see to work fine after deleting cache.Is there any way/code in angular to delete cache